# Combine program with argument and without argument

Tags: python

I want a Python program which have to ask user to give values as arguments.
If user runs simply (without argument) the program it have to print

```
$ python prog.py

Hello
```

If user gives arguments as Welcome it have to print Welcome.

```
$ python prog.py Welcome

Welcome
```

Comment: I upvoted because there's some good answers, but downvoed because this question is too broad and unclear (there're two possible answers). And voted to close it because you didn't try anything but want us write code for you. **Please remember that SO is a question and answer site, not a code write site. You should try something, and if you got an error then ask here next time.**

Answer (score 3):

`sys.argv` contains a list of runtime arguments, with the filename of script as first argument:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print(" ".join(sys.argv[1:]))
else:
    print("Hello")
```

$ python script.py foo bar

```
foo bar

$ python script.py
Hello
```

Comment: `sys.argv[1]` will raise an exception if there's no argument :-)

Comment: It shows this error

[root@localhost python]# python arg.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arg.py", line 3, in <module>
    if sys.argv[1]:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Forgot that change the `if` to `if len(sys.argv)>1:`

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes thanks I definitely goofed up here.

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print(' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
else:
    print('Hello')
```

**Output:**

```
➜  python stackoverflow.py
Hello
➜  python stackoverflow.py Welcome to Miami!
Welcome to Miami!
```

Comment: @DhanasekarSR great! Please don't forget accepting my answer if it helped you solve the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 'Welcome')
```

This will print `Welcome` if there's no arguments, and print the first argument if there's arguments.

Demo:

```
kevin@Arch ~> python test.py 
Welcome
kevin@Arch ~> python test.py Hey
Hey
kevin@Arch ~> python test.py Hey there
Hey
```

If you'd like print `Hey there` when the arguments are `Hey there`, simply use:

```
import sys
print(' '.join(sys.argv[1:]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 'Welcome')
```

Here's more details about [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

Comment: `print(''.join(sys.argv) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 'hello')` : for >1 args

Comment: @AyushShanker it should be actually `print(''.join(sys.argv[1:]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 'hello')`

Comment: Removing previous comments :)

Answer (score 1):

You may test the size of the argument list, for example:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print(sys.argv[1])
else:
    print("Hello")
```

Or use a `try:` block:

```
try:
    print(sys.argv[1])
except IndexError:
    print("Hello")
```